# probability for a post

Tags: probability

If there is one post and two candidates . Probability of selection of A is 1/7 and of B is 2/5. We have to find the probability for one of being them is selected .

I thought as

P(A'B') = (1/7)(2/5) as this would give the probability for one being selected .

Am I correct , if not then wht is the correct method .

In a book solution is given as [image]

Comment: Is it not just $\frac17+\frac25=\frac{19}{35}$?

Comment: Is it not forbidden that both candidates can be chosen for the same post?

Comment: $A'B'$ is the event that neither candidate is selected (someone else is).

Comment: @user123733 Find out if you can get a refund for that book.  It's clearly not worth what you paid.  The solution assumes that the selection of candidates for the post is independent.

Comment: @GrahamKemp how can we tell it assumes that

Comment: It uses $p(A\cap B')=p(A)p(B')$ which is *only* true if they are independent.

Comment: ... worse, it does that *and* uses $p(A\cap B)=0$ . $$p(A\cup B) = p(A\cap B')+p(A'\cap B)+p(A\cap B) \\ \not\equiv p(A)p(B')+p(A')p(B)$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp if they are not independent then how can we write $p(A\cap B')$.

Comment: @koolman If the events $A,B$ are disjoint, then: $p(A\cap B')=p(A)$ by definition of disjoint.

Answer (score 5):

No, that's not correct.   $A'B'$ is the event that neither candidate is selected (either someone else is, or the post is left empty).

Since only one candidate *can* be selected, the events are mutually exclusive (also known as "disjoint").   The probability of their union is thus the sum of their probabilities.

$$\require{cancel}P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)\color{silver}{\cancelto{0}{-P(A\cap B)}}$$

---

The solution in the book is clearly incorrect too.   It assumes that the selection of candidates for the post are somehow independent *and* disjoint.

Comment: What will we do if they are not independent

Comment: @user123733 As stated, if the events are disjoint, then the probability of their union is thus the sum of their probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

(Supplementing Graham Kemp's answer)

The given probabilities can be interpreted as follows: Imagine that there is a board of $35$ members. $5$ of these would hire $A$,  $14$ of these would hire $B$, and the rest would hire none of the two. One of the board members is then  picked at random, and his opinion is made final. The  probability that one of $A$ or $B$ is hired is therefore given by ${5+14\over 35}={19\over35}$.